# Partial derivatives + Taylor's Formula in several variables

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

Given a function $f(x) = (x_1+...+x_n)^k$, how do we show that $$D_1^{j_1}\cdots D_n^{j_n}f(x) = k!$$
if $j_1+...+j_n = k$?

Comment: Try applying the chain rule over and over again ($k$ times, to be precise).  Particularly, since $f\, : \, \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, the chain rule takes a particularly nice form, namely:
$$f_{x_i} = k(x_1 + \ldots + x_n)^{k-1}\partial_{x_i}(x_1+\ldots+x_n)$$
and $\partial_{x_i}(x_1+\ldots+x_n) = 1$, so iterating, the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

Simplify the problem: let $f_k(x) = x^k, g(x_1,\dots x_n) = \sum_{l=1}^n x_l$.

$\left(\sum_{l=1}^n x_l\right)^k = f\circ g(x_1,\dots,x_n)$.

Now $$
D_j  f_k\circ g(x_1,\dots,x_n) = f_k'\circ g(x_1,\dots,x_n) \times 1
=k f_{k-1}\circ g(x_1,\dots,x_n) \\= \frac{k!}{(k-1)!} 
f_{k-1}\circ g(x_1,\dots,x_n)
\\
D_{1}^{j_1} \dots D_{n}^{j_n}  f_k\circ g(x_1,\dots,x_n)
=\frac{k!}{(k-\sum_{l=1}^n j_l)!} 
f_{k-\sum_{l=1}^n j_l}\circ g(x_1,\dots,x_n)
$$

with an easy induction.

Now if $\sum_{l=1}^n j_l=k$ this becomes, as $f_0 = 1$:
$$
D_{1}^{j_1} \dots D_{n}^{j_n} (f_k\circ g)= k!
$$